# How to run two threads simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

```
from threading import Thread
import time
class ThreadTest():

    def loop1(self):
        for i in range(0, 100, 5):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(2)

    def loop2(self):
        for i in range(100, 210, 11):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    T1 = Thread(target=ThreadTest().loop1(), args=())
    T2 = Thread(target=ThreadTest().loop2(), args=())
    T1.start()
    T2.start()
    T1.join()
    T2.join()
```

The above code runs the methods in sequence rather than simultaneously. I want a way where I can run two method/process simultaneously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple bug in your code.

Replace:

```
T1 = Thread(target=ThreadTest().loop1(), args=())
T2 = Thread(target=ThreadTest().loop2(), args=())
```

With:

```
T1 = Thread(target=ThreadTest().loop1, args=())
T2 = Thread(target=ThreadTest().loop2, args=())
```

Because you're calling the functions `loop1()` and `loop2()` in the main thread, they're going to run sequentially. You want to point to the functions, without actually calling them so the subthreads can call them themselves.